# Loading Large Image Effeciently in Recycle View

Tags: android

I have 10 images that i want to display all having around 400x400 dimensions. Im loading the images in Recycle View. However the Images loads and lags alot where i can barely even scroll.
I get the following warnings

> Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

So this is my recycleview

```
 @Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = infator.inflate(R.layout.customerow,parent,false);

    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);

    text1.setTypeface(assent);




    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    Information current = data.get(position);
    //Picasso.with(context1).load(current.IconId).into(holder.image1);
    holder.text1.setText(current.title);
    holder.image1.setImageResource(current.IconId);

    holder.image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void onClick(View v) {
                                             Toast.makeText(context1,"Item clicked"+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




                                         }

                                     }

    );

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

  public   TextView text1;
  public   ImageView image1;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        text1 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        image1=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    }
}
```

Im loading the image from drawable

```
public static List<Information> getdata(){
    List<Information> data=new ArrayList<>();
    int[] icons={R.drawable.pa,R.drawable.house_abc,R.drawable.abc_avc,R.drawable.strength_beastmaster,
                    R.drawable.strength_brewmaster,R.drawable.strength_bristleback,R.drawable.strength_centaur};
```

Im just learning so can you guys help me out

Comment: What is original size of images, which are you using?

Comment: @ArturSzymański The orginal image size are 400x400 and im displaying the image in imageview of 200dp by 200dp. The image are stored in drawable

Comment: Was it lagging with picasse?

Comment: @EugeneH Im not downloading the images, isnt picasse mostly used while downloading the images?therefore i didnt use picasse here. But yes i tried picasse and it still lagged

Comment: I usually use picasso for loading a lot of images regardless of web or within the app.  I am assuming it is the recyclerview keep loading the images when they go off screen.  That is where picasso would help.

Answer (score 0):

I have an advice, [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) is documentation about supporting multiple screens. Especially you should read about "Alternative drawables". In this article you can find modifiers what sizes should have all images for specific densities. You should scale all your images and put them to correct folder.